# How to parse and extract texts from a badly formatted XML documents using Python 3 or Python 2

Tags: xml, python-3.x, documentation

I am currently working on a project and it involves taking an input of an XML document. Unfortunately, the document is not structured correctly and has a `encoding="ISO-8859-1"` instead of a `encoding="utf-8"`. Moreover, the document has a series of other tags and objects within the file that makes it hard to retrieve text from a specific tag using python's Element Tree Library. 
Here is my code which is a function of a class that parses a XML document :

When I ran my code, I received the following:

> lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Namespace prefix lndocmeta on docinfo is not defined, line 1, column 170

However, when I open the XML file in Internet Explorer, the document opens to a blank page. However, when I open it in Google Chrome, the XML document shows up properly.

Any suggestions which would be beneficial?

Comment: Please see [ask]. Show your research. What code are you using? What results did you get? Parsers can be strict or not, so see what happens if you try a few different things.

Comment: I was unable to send screenshots.

Comment: You don't need screenshots. You can show some example XML as formatted text and show what you are trying to do to it, and what errors you get. Ideally, we want to see a [mcve]. Basically, no one is going to write code for you especially based on some unknown specification.